# MEF, creating Import's tree when a branch is requested

Tags: c#, .net, mvp, mef

Using MEF I want to do the following.

I have a WPF Shell. To the shell I want to Import from another DLL a UserControl that is also a View of my MVP triad.
The way the MVP triad works, is that in presenter I have a constructor that takes both IModel and IView and wires them up.
So, in order for this to work, I need MEF to do the following:

1. Create IView implementation
2. Create IModel implementation
3. Create Presenter and pass IModel and IView to its constructor
4. Import IView implementation into my shell when it gets displayed

Instead what it does, is it only creates the type Exporting IView and passes it to the shell, basically skipping steps 2 and 3. Its pretty logical, when you think about it, but how can I tell MEF to also create the whole triad when I ask for a IView.
I don't need to reference Presenter nor model anywhere else in my Shell .dll so puting it as an Import as well is not an option (and it would be quite ugly anyway :).

I'm using the latest drop of MEF (Preview 2 Refresh).
Anyone?

**==Update==**

I have found a solution and I blogged about it here:
[Krzysztof Koźmic's blog - Creating tree of dependencies with MEF](http://kozmic.pl/archive/2008/11/06/creating-tree-of-dependencies-with-mef/)

However, I'd be more than happy if someone came up with a better solution.**

Comment: Did you put [ImportingConstructor] on the constructor?

Comment: Yes I did, check the link I provided, there is a simplified version of the code, and my solution. It works but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check my answer here.

http://codebetter.com/blogs/glenn.block/archive/2008/11/12/mvp-with-mef.aspx

EDIT: (*Added from the link, to prevent not being flagged as low quality / LOA*)

```
   1: using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
   2: using System.Reflection;
   3: using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
   4:  
   5: namespace MVPwithMEF
   6: {
   7:     /// <summary>
   8:     /// Summary description for MVPTriadFixture
   9:     /// </summary>
  10:     [TestClass]
  11:     public class MVPTriadFixture
  12:     {
  13:         [TestMethod]
  14:         public void MVPTriadShouldBeProperlyBuilt()
  15:         {
  16:             var catalog = new AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
  17:             var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog.CreateResolver());
  18:             var shell = container.GetExportedObject<Shell>();
  19:             Assert.IsNotNull(shell);
  20:             Assert.IsNotNull(shell.Presenter);
  21:             Assert.IsNotNull(shell.Presenter.View);
  22:             Assert.IsNotNull(shell.Presenter.Model);
  23:         }
  24:     }
  25:  
  26:     [Export]
  27:     public class Shell
  28:     {
  29:         private IPresenter _presenter = null;
  30:         
  31:         public IPresenter Presenter
  32:         {
  33:             get { return _presenter; }
  34:         }
  35:  
  36:         [ImportingConstructor]
  37:         public Shell(IPresenter presenter)
  38:         {
  39:             _presenter = presenter;
  40:         }
  41:     }
  42:  
  43:     public interface IModel
  44:     {
  45:     }
  46:  
  47:     [Export(typeof(IModel))]
  48:     public class Model : IModel
  49:     {
  50:         
  51:     }
  52:  
  53:     public interface IView
  54:     {
  55:     }
  56:  
  57:     [Export(typeof(IView))]
  58:     public class View : IView
  59:     {
  60:     }
  61:  
  62:     public interface IPresenter
  63:     {
  64:         IView View { get;}
  65:         IModel Model { get; }
  66:     }
  67:  
  68:     [Export(typeof(IPresenter))]
  69:     public class Presenter : IPresenter
  70:     {
  71:  
  72:         private IView _view;
  73:         private IModel _model;
  74:  
  75:         [ImportingConstructor]
  76:         public Presenter(IView view, IModel model)
  77:         {
  78:             _view = view;
  79:             _model = model;
  80:         }
  81:  
  82:         public IView View
  83:         {
  84:             get { return _view; }
  85:         }
  86:  
  87:         public IModel Model
  88:         {
  89:             get { return _model; }
  90:         }
  91:  
  92:     }
  93: }
```

So what’s going on here?

Shell gets injected with Presenter. Presenter gets injected with View and Model. Everything here is singletons, but doesn’t have to be.

The difference between our two examples is that the Presenter is getting injected into the shell rather than the View. If the Presenter is creating the View then you can’t just grab the View first (as he was doing), or the Presenter will not get created. Well you can do it, but you end up hacking it to bits. Cleaner is to just inject the Presenter and have it expose an IView. We did this in Prism and it worked quite well.

Comment: (+1) while this seems to answer the question, it is considered a low quality post as the answer is just a link. It is much better if, in addition to the link, a description or summary of the problem and the solution offered in the link were in order. thought i'd leave a note here as it *was flagged* as low-quality.

Answer (score 1):

The way you outlined in your blog post is the perfectly valid way for utilizing MEF. This is nested composition, and while designing it is always good to keep in mind that Container is the decider, so as a plug-in / extender vendor you will focus on your services that you are "exporting" and as an important, you shouldn't worry about what you need to be serviced, or "importing" (this point has some issues in the last drop, but I hear good enough to be optimistic about it).

So in nested composition, you may need some external services but at the time you can also be providing some. When you do a compose, it will plug everything together.

I have a blog post containing 2 examples illustrating this way of thinking :

http://www.sidarok.com/web/blog/content/2008/09/26/what-is-this-managed-extensibility-framework-thing-all-about.html

Also, to drop the dll and watch the types in it, you can use DirectoryPartCatalog to watch that folder.

You will also need to watch out the scenarios where there are multiple exports for the same contract, and determine the right one from metadata provided.